# Java response content returns instead of < or > &lt; &gt;

Tags: java, http-headers, httpresponse, resin

I have a little problem: I'm writing to response content of the file and return it to the client as an ajax response.
But there occurs html substitution: of `>` to `&gt;` etc...
What i have to do to make this substitution off ?

```
res.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" );
res.setHeader( "Pragma", "public" );
res.setContentType( "text/html" );
```

TIA

update

```
//    import com.ibm.useful.http.PostData;
        PostData pd = new PostData( req );
        final FileData data;

    try {
        data = pd.getFileData( "sqlFile" );

    ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for ( byte b : data.getByteData() ) {
       buf.write( b );
    }
    res.getWriter().print( buf.toString() );
}
```

i watched `buf.toString()` through debugger. it's ok there. substitution goes further. but where...

Comment: Where's the code you use to write the file contents to the response?

Comment: How are you writing response? Can you provide some example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML special characters are been escaped into [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

If you are *sure* that this happened right after you wrote it to the response and right before the response data arrives at the client, then there's possibly a filter in the chain which has escaped the HTML entities for some reason. Check the declared filters in `web.xml` and adjust the `url-pattern` if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when html characters (

> <, > , "

amongst others) are being escaped.
Try setting escape to false or similar. 
Can't find the api documentation for "com.ibm.useful.http.PostData"

Answer (score 0):

Try using below snippet:

```
res.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Please make sure your database is set to UTF-8 encoding as well, if your using one.

If this doesn't solve, please read this [article](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/958).

Comment: This problem has nothing but also really nothing to do with character encoding.

Comment: Also refer the article I have added in the answer.